# memory leak Tdelegated comparer

Tags: delphi

I#m writing a generic graph lib in delphi .

the code below shows implementation of TGraph and Tvertex

```
///  TGRAPH ....
constructor TGraph<Tdata>.Create( ...);
begin
  // the graph owns its vertices - by freeing of the graph one frees the vertex list!
  _vertices := TObjectList < TVertex < Tdata >>
    .Create(TVertex<Tdata>.createVertexComparer(), true);

  _edges := TObjectList < TEdge < Tdata >>
    .Create(TEdge<Tdata>.createEdgeComparer(), true); 
end;

// destroy the graph and all its elemenst!
destructor TGraph<Tdata>.Free;

begin
  _edges.Free;
  _vertices.Free;
end;


/// Tvertex ......
class function TVertex<T>.createVertexComparer(): IComparer<TVertex<T>>;
begin
  Result := TDelegatedComparer < TVertex < T >>.Create(
    function(const Left, Right: TVertex<T>): Integer
    begin
      Result := Left.Compare(Right);
    end);

end;

constructor TVertex<T>.Create(withID: Integer);
begin
  F_neighbours := TObjectList < TVertex < T >>
    .Create(TVertex<T>.createVertexComparer(), true);
  vertex_id := withID;
end;

function TVertex<T>.Compare(const v: TVertex<T>): Integer;
begin
  Result := (self.fId - v.vertex_id);
end;

destructor TVertex<T>.Free;
begin
  F_neighbours.Free;
  // F_neighbours := nil;
  FreeAndNil(Fdata);
end;
```

If I run the code i find a memory leak report with FastMM4 as shown in the screen dump.
I can not understand why TdelegatedComparer is leaky ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> destructor TGraph.Free;
>
> destructor TVertex.Free;

The correct destructor name is `Destroy`, and it must be declared as an `override` since it is `virtual` in `TObject`:

```
type
  TGraph<T> = class(...)
  ...
  public
    ...
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

destructor TGraph<T>.Destroy;
begin
  _edges.Free;
  _vertices.Free;
  inherited; // <-- and don't forget this
end;
```

```
type
  TVertex<T> = class(...)
    ...
  public
    ...
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

destructor TVertex<T>.Destroy;
begin
  F_neighbours.Free;
  // F_neighbours := nil;
  FreeAndNil(Fdata);
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: the vertex comparer is still not yet freed again after changing destructor methode name

Comment: You have not yet shown any code that actually creates and destroys  `TGraph` and `TVertex` objects.  All you have shown are their constructors and destructors, but not the code that actually calls them.  Please show that code.